# Finding periodic points of every period, Sharkovskii's Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Consider the map:
$C_c(x)=c\cos(x)$

(a) Find a value of the parameter c for which this map has prime periodic points of every period,
and provide an explanation with graphs supporting your argument.

(b) Find a value of the parameter c for which this map has periodic points of every period except prime period 3, and provide an explanation with graphs supporting your argument

If I understand Sharkovskii's Theorem correctly, I would have to find c values such that for part a) there will be a 3-cycle and for part b) there will be a 5-cycle. If I am correct, how would I find such fixed points? It is a bit harder since I have to deal with $\cos(x)$

Comment: For the first part, do you know whether $\cos(x)$ has a fixed point?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ccos%28ccos%28ccos%28pi%2F2%29%29%29%3Dpi%2F2

Comment: @DanielRust, cos(x) does have a fixed point at approximately x'=0.74. So I was playing around on grapher and noticed that at c=-2.5, there are prime period n points for the nth iterate where n is in the neighbourhood of 3. Can I conclude from that and Sharkovskii's Theorem that the map has periodic of points of every period?